# Deamortization of basic COLA (Cache oblivious lookahead array)

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, cache-oblivious

I am reading the paper titled [Cache Oblivious Streaming B-trees](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/sbtree.pdf). I am trying to understand the deamortization technique used for basic COLA.

The paper says that for every level k, for deamortization, it keeps 2 arrays of size 2^k. This is added space. Is this the technique of using redundant binary ? How does this help in deamortization ? Do the added bits that are introduced help in merging the arrays in O(1) time ?

Any explanation on the details of this deamortization will be of great help.